# Add to CDN in ySlow Chrome extension

Tags: php, performance, yslow

I've added CDN on my php site and all of a sudden AJAX requests stopped working.

What would have caused this issue!?

Do I have to take CDN out? If so, what could I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cdn allows you to serve different scripts/images etc from different domains or apache instances. This eases the weight on the server and should make the website load faster.
CDN isn't useful on a small site really.

the problem im guessing is the scripts are being served from different domains which is causing problems. use the cdn to deliver images could work. without seeing a bit more code thats the best I can do :)